# Swift vapor 3 ViewRenderer error

Tags: swift, vapor, leaf

That's the error

> Please choose which ViewRenderer you prefer, multiple are available: PlaintextRenderer, LeafRenderer.

that's my code in **configure.swift**

```
try services.register(LeafProvider())
config.prefer(LeafRenderer.self, for: TemplateRenderer.self)
```

Leaf added to **Package.swift**

```
.target(name: "App", dependencies: ["Vapor", "FluentSQLite", "Crypto", "Leaf"]),
```

Although I did **vapor xcode** , **Build** and **Run** as well , But it still refuses to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// As of Vapor 3.0.1 and Leaf 3.0.0-rc.2.2
config.prefer(LeafRenderer.self, for: ViewRenderer.self)
```

Comment: It should. How are you rendering your views ?